# Matlab - for loop in anonymus function

Tags: matlab, for-loop, anonymous-function

I'm quite new to matlab, but I know how to do both for loops and anonymous functions. Now I would like to combine these.

I want to write:

`sa = @(c) for i = 1:numel(biscs{c}), figure(i), imshow(biscs{c}{i}.Image), end;`

But that isn't valid, since matlab seem to want newlines as only command-seperator. My code written in a clear way would be (without function header):

```
for i = 1:numel(biscs{c})
    figure(i)
    imshow(biscs{c}{i}.Image)
end
```

I look for a solution where either I can write it with an anonymous function in a single line like my first example. I would also be happy if I could create that function another way, as long as I don't need a new function m-file for i.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Anonymous functions can contain multiple statements, but no explicit loops or if-clauses. The multiple statements are passed in a cell array, and are evaluated one after another. For example this function will open a figure and plot some data:

```
fun = @(i,c){figure(i),imshow(imshow(biscs{c}{i}.Image)}
```

This doesn't solve the problem of the loop, however. Fortunately, there is [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html). With this, you can write your loop as follows:

```
sa = @(c)arrayfun(@(i){figure(i),imshow(biscs{c}{i}.Image)},...
         1:numel(biscs{c}),'uniformOutput',false)
```

Conveniently, this function also returns the outputs of `figure` and `imshow`, i.e. the respective handles.

Answer (score 9):

If you're calling this function from another function, you can define it at the end of the main function's .m file, then refer to it using the @name syntax.  This doesn't work from script files, though, as these cannot contain sub functions.

A second approach is somewhat dirty, but nevertheless might work, and is to use eval STRING:

```
fun = @(a,b) eval('for i = 1:a; imshow(b(i)); end');
```

It would be great if script files could allow the definition of sub functions somehow, but this is unlikely.