# MATLAB: Function to calculate true Elo performance rating

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to make a function that calculates the true Elo performance rating in relation to games of chess.

It would take in:

1. A vector of game_results, e.g. [1 0 0.5] which indicates the player won the first game, lost the second game, and drew the third. From this we would get another variable score, which here is 1.5, and another variable num_games, which here is 3.
2. A vector of opponent_ratings, e.g. [1200 1400 1350] which indicates the first opponent was rated 1200, the second 1400, and the third 1350.

I know that the true performance rating is x in the following equation:

```
for i = 1:num_games        
    score = score + (1/(1+10^((opp_ratings(i)-x)/400)));        
end
```

What is needed is to find the right value of `x` to make score here add up to the actual score 1.5.

Here I happen to know that `x=1317.55` will produce approximately the right answer.

It seems to me like I would need to pass an anonymous function containing that code above to some other optimizing function. However:

1. I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664021/1205197) that anonymous functions can't contain loops.
2. I'm not sure what optimizing function would be appropriate. MATLAB does not seem to have any native bisection function.

Comment: You don’t need to use an anonymous function. You need to pass a handle to a function. You can write your function in a file called, for example, `myfun.m`, and then obtain a handle with `@myfun`. Anonymous functions are just a special case of function handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non linear equation solver such as `fsolve`.

`fsolve` will find the value of `x` for the equation `f(x) == 0`.

So you can create the function `f(x)` and run `fsolve`:

```
opp_ratings = [1200 1400 1350];
tot_score   = 1.5
f           = @(x) sum(1./(1+10.^((opp_ratings-x)/400)))-tot_score; 
res         = fsolve(f,0) %the second argument is the initial point x0

% res       =  1317.6
```

Noticed that I've linearized your for loop using the operators `.^` (element wise power operator) and `./` (element wise division). So now it's way easier to define a one line equation `f(x)`.

Also, it's a detail, but in order to improve the fsolve performance (reduce the number of iteration needed) you can for example set the initial x0 value equal "the average ELO rating" let's say 1000. So `fsolve(f,1000)` will statistically converge faster.

**Not recommanded:**

If your equation could not have been linearized, you indeed could have written `f(x)` like that:

```
f = @(x) sum(arrayfun(@(opp_ratings) (1/(1+10^((opp_ratings-x)/400))),opp_ratings))-tot_score
```

using arrayfun. But avoid this solution if possible (because it's ugly, and a little bit slower).